# Coffeescript: return true or false in one-liner

Tags: coffeescript

For an example function like:

```
singleDigits = (list) ->
    return false for i in list when i > 9
    true
```

I'm wondering whether or not that would be possible without the lone `true`at the end
e.g.

```
singleDigits = (list) -> return true unless false for i in list when i > 9
```

(I know that is not working, just to illustrate what I'm asking)

Answer (score 3):

I think you could use the `some` method in `Array`.

```
someDigits = (list) -> list.some (digit) -> digit > 9
```

The advantage over reduce is that it will stop in the moment the predicate becomes true, whereas reduce will still finish going over the entire array.

See [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) reference.

Comment: Oh good call, I never remember all the native methods - too much underscore.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
singleDigits = (list) ->
    list.reduce (previous = true, next) -> previous and next < 10
```